Webform Composite Element Loses Required Asterisk After Add Item
My webform contains the following elements:

A group_nomination radio element.
A first_name text_field element
A composite element with a first_name text field.

All elements are required.
The first_name element is Visible when Group Nomination Value is No.
The composite element is Visible when Group Nomination Value is Yes.
I create a reference node for the form. When I select Yes for Group Nomination, First Name becomes Visible and has an asterisk.

When I click Add, a second first-name item is added to the form, but the asterisk on both the first and second first_name items are now not printing.

If I switch Group Nomination to No and then back to Yes, the asterisks print.
It looks like the required-mark::after from form.css is what's missing after clicking the Add button.
Has anyone seen this before?
Here's the webform:
uuid: 1baf6c4e-2420-4ae8-a88f-da9607f12055
langcode: en
status: open
dependencies: {  }
weight: 0
open: null
close: null
uid: null
template: false
archive: false
id: my_form
title: 'My Form'
description: ''
categories: {  }
elements: |-
  group_nomination:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'Group Nomination'
    '#options': yes_no
    '#options_display': side_by_side
    '#required': true
  first_name:
    '#type': textfield
    '#title': 'First Name'
    '#required': true
    '#states':
      visible:
        ':input[name="group_nomination"]':
          value: 'No'
  members:
    '#type': webform_custom_composite
    '#title': Members
    '#states':
      visible:
        ':input[name="group_nomination"]':
          value: 'Yes'
    '#multiple__header': false
    '#multiple__header_label': "Members' Information"
    '#multiple__item_label': member
    '#multiple__sorting': false
    '#multiple__add': false
    '#multiple__add_more_input': false
    '#format_items': ol
    '#element':
      first_name:
        '#type': textfield
        '#required': true
        '#title': 'First Name'
css: ''
javascript: ''
settings:
  ajax: false
  ajax_scroll_top: form
  ajax_progress_type: ''
  ajax_effect: ''
  ajax_speed: null
  page: false
  page_submit_path: ''
  page_confirm_path: ''
  page_theme_name: ''
  form_title: both
  form_submit_once: false
  form_open_message: ''
  form_close_message: ''
  form_exception_message: ''
  form_previous_submissions: true
  form_confidential: false
  form_confidential_message: ''
  form_disable_remote_addr: false
  form_convert_anonymous: false
  form_prepopulate: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity_required: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity_type: ''
  form_unsaved: false
  form_disable_back: false
  form_submit_back: false
  form_disable_autocomplete: false
  form_novalidate: false
  form_disable_inline_errors: false
  form_required: false
  form_autofocus: false
  form_details_toggle: false
  form_reset: false
  form_access_denied: default
  form_access_denied_title: ''
  form_access_denied_message: ''
  form_access_denied_attributes: {  }
  form_file_limit: ''
  form_attributes: {  }
  form_method: ''
  form_action: ''
  share: false
  share_node: false
  share_theme_name: ''
  share_title: true
  share_page_body_attributes: {  }
  submission_label: ''
  submission_exception_message: ''
  submission_locked_message: ''
  submission_log: false
  submission_excluded_elements: {  }
  submission_exclude_empty: false
  submission_exclude_empty_checkbox: false
  submission_views: {  }
  submission_views_replace: {  }
  submission_user_columns: {  }
  submission_user_duplicate: false
  submission_access_denied: default
  submission_access_denied_title: ''
  submission_access_denied_message: ''
  submission_access_denied_attributes: {  }
  previous_submission_message: ''
  previous_submissions_message: ''
  autofill: false
  autofill_message: ''
  autofill_excluded_elements: {  }
  wizard_progress_bar: true
  wizard_progress_pages: false
  wizard_progress_percentage: false
  wizard_progress_link: false
  wizard_progress_states: false
  wizard_start_label: ''
  wizard_preview_link: false
  wizard_confirmation: true
  wizard_confirmation_label: ''
  wizard_auto_forward: true
  wizard_auto_forward_hide_next_button: false
  wizard_keyboard: true
  wizard_track: ''
  wizard_prev_button_label: ''
  wizard_next_button_label: ''
  wizard_toggle: false
  wizard_toggle_show_label: ''
  wizard_toggle_hide_label: ''
  wizard_page_type: container
  wizard_page_title_tag: h2
  preview: 0
  preview_label: ''
  preview_title: ''
  preview_message: ''
  preview_attributes: {  }
  preview_excluded_elements: {  }
  preview_exclude_empty: true
  preview_exclude_empty_checkbox: false
  draft: none
  draft_multiple: false
  draft_auto_save: false
  draft_saved_message: ''
  draft_loaded_message: ''
  draft_pending_single_message: ''
  draft_pending_multiple_message: ''
  confirmation_type: page
  confirmation_url: ''
  confirmation_title: ''
  confirmation_message: ''
  confirmation_attributes: {  }
  confirmation_back: true
  confirmation_back_label: ''
  confirmation_back_attributes: {  }
  confirmation_exclude_query: false
  confirmation_exclude_token: false
  confirmation_update: false
  limit_total: null
  limit_total_interval: null
  limit_total_message: ''
  limit_total_unique: false
  limit_user: null
  limit_user_interval: null
  limit_user_message: ''
  limit_user_unique: false
  entity_limit_total: null
  entity_limit_total_interval: null
  entity_limit_user: null
  entity_limit_user_interval: null
  purge: none
  purge_days: null
  results_disabled: false
  results_disabled_ignore: false
  results_customize: false
  token_view: false
  token_update: false
  token_delete: false
  serial_disabled: false
access:
  create:
    roles:
      - anonymous
      - authenticated
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  view_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  update_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  delete_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  purge_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  view_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  update_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  delete_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  administer:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  test:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  configuration:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
handlers: {  }
variants: {  }


Before clicking Add, the markup contains js-form-required form-required in the label which may be responsible for the required="required" aria-required="true" attributes in the input.
Here is the before clicking 'Add' screen shot of the markup.

Here is the after clicking 'Add' screenshot.


At the edge of my mind there is a memory of an existing bug report about this, but I'm not sure. It could be a Drupal Core bug.

have definitely seen issues with asterisk not showing when it should - but possibly in a very different context - but iirc correctly a colleague said it was due to the Theme - it might be worth trying with another theme just to see if that makes any difference.

Thanks. The question is based on Drupal 10.3, Olivero default theme, Claro administration theme, Webform 6.2.2, no custom code. This is Plain Vanilla Drupal. js-form-required form-required disappears from the label when clicking Add. As well as required="required" aria-required"true" disappearing from the input when clicking Add. I'm adding screen shots of the markup to the question.
